# Small bug at 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: system-installation

i have installed 29.04.3 LTS on a mini pc Beelink ser7 ryzen 7840hs.
There are a couple of errors prompted such as AE_NOT_FOUND

Ubuntu seems to working well, but there are some dysfunctions; the audio jack output doesnt work, and when pluging an USB web cam, Cheese software gives a black screen.

I found it could be a problem of kernel version, but it s not clear how to solve.

Please, what shall be done exactly to install properly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is a LTS release, meaning you have kernel stack choice with the default being set by the media you used to install. You didn't specify which product (Server, Desktop) so we won't know your defaults (I suspect Desktop), but stack details can be found documented here - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack with 6.2 being the current HWE kernel, 5.15 the GA kernel, and various OEM options depending on your *unstated* hardware.